# unexpected Token { error

Tags: javascript

I need help with an error on my javascript code. I want if `is_hadir == 1` then check box is checked.

error code is in this section :

```
".if(data[i].is_hadir == 1){checked = true;}else{checked = false}."
```

and this is my code

```
for (var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){                 
    html = html +
           "<tr>"+
           "<td>"+data[i].nip+"</td>"+
           "<td>"+data[i].nm_dosen+"</td>"+
           "<td>"+data[i].email+"</td>"+
           "<td>"+data[i].no_telp+"</td>"+
           "<td><input type='checkbox' ".if(data[i].is_hadir == 1){checked = true;}else{checked = false}." name='Nip[]' onclick='cek(this,"+data[i].id_rapat+","+data[i].nip+")' value="+data[i].nip+"> </td>"+                                     
           "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, concatenation is using `+`, not `.`. Second, you need to use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
"<td><input type='checkbox' " + (data[i].is_hadir == 1? 'checked' : '') + " name='Nip[...
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Luis said, you used `.` instead of `+` for your concatenation, but I would also recommend using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of concatenation like you are doing. It will greatly improve readability and edit-ability as you could do change all that code to something like this:

```
html = `${ html }
<tr>
    <td>${ data[i].nip }</td>
    <td>${ data[i].nm_dosen }</td>
    <td>${ data[i].email }</td>
    <td>${ data[i].no_telp }</td>
    <td>
        <input type='checkbox' 
            checked='${ !!data[i].is_hadir }' name='${ Nip[] }'
            onclick='cek(this, ${ data[i].id_rapat }, ${ data[i].nip })'
            value='${ data[i].nip }'>
    </td>                                     
</tr>`;
```

Also, you should probably add an event listener to the input instead of injecting into the `onclick` directly (you likely are introducing some XSS bugs doing it this way), but that's it's own separate issue.

Hopefully you can see how this could improve your current code.